# Maximum Sum of Factors of Numbers in a given Range

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, number-theory, factorization

This is a question I've been doing on some online judge platform.

Find the maximum sum of factors of numbers from 1 to N.

For instance, if N were to be 11, the answer will be 18. The number with the greatest sum of factors from 1 to 11 is 10 (1 + 2 + 5 + 10).

I implemented a relatively straightforward solution that looks like a sieve. The code in C++ is as shown below:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; ++i {
    for (int j = i; j <= 1000000; j += i) {
        num[j] += i;
    }
    mx[i] = max(num[i], mx[i - 1]);
}
```

Whenever the user queries for some N, I simpy output `mx[N]`. This solution seems to be correct. However, it exceeds time limit(1s) for larger inputs. Maximum N is 1,000,000 but the user may query for 1,000,000 different values of N. The above code is a pre-processing code that is run once.

The complexity of the above code is N + N / 2 + N / 3 + ... + 1 which I suppose is about N Log N. How do I improve the complexity of this code?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Think about prime factorization.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb If I were to use prime factorization, wouldn't that be too time-consuming? Correct me if I'm wrong, but with prime factorization, I'd have to find all the prime factors of a number before proceeding to calculate the sum of factors.

Comment: This question is too vague for stack overflow.   There are an unlimited number of answers possible.   Please focus your question on a specific aspect of your code.

Comment: @xaxxon Allow me to edit my question.

Comment: Search for Sieve of Eratosthenes it's complexity is O(nlog(log(n)) almost O(n).

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb If I use Sieve of Eratosthenes to calculate the prime numbers up till 1,000,000, wouldn't then permutating between the powers of the prime numbers to get the sum of divisors exceed the time limit?

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb In addition, the Sieve of Eratosthenes' inner loop seems very similar to my code's inner loop. Thus, wouldn't it too have about the same complexity?

Comment: After creating your sieve think about memorising the already calculated sum and use them later , ex if you already calculated the sum of divisors of 35 then you don't need to recalculate them for 70 = 35 * 2

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan reviewing working code is what http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is for

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb Thanks for your help. I didn't think of that. I'll proceed to edit my code.

Comment: Thanks, well it just a thought it may be wrong, as I didn't have the problem, can you share a link to the problem?

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb I'm sorry but this problem is in a private online judge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of this problem is: [Highly Abundant Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_abundant_number)
You can get sequence from here: [A002093](https://oeis.org/A002093/b002093.txt) 

Actually, I checked that all highly abundant number below 10^10 is 41-smooth number, and below 10^13 is 61-smooth number.
N-smooth number can factorize primes below N.
You can search n-smooth number like this algorithm (ex. 47-smooth number below 10^16):

```
vector<int> p = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47 };
vector<long long> s = { 1 }; long long lim = 10000000000000000;
for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
    vector<long long> w;
    for (long long j : s) {
        long long mul = j;
        for (; mul <= lim; mul *= p[i]) w.push_back(mul);
    }
    s = w;
}
```

You can factorize N-smooth number X in `O(log N + log X)`, so you can calculate [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) for `O(log N + log X)`.

I give a result of my code, for example, I calculated all 61-smooth numbers below 10^13, in 3.5 sec, using 1GB of memory.

Comment: some comments to explain what's going on would make this more useful.  Also, what do you mean "time complexity is heuristic"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number), the HCN n column does not have the number 10 in it. However, in my illustration, 10 is a number whose factor sum is greater than the next number 11. Does a large number of divisors correlate with the largest sum of divisors?

Comment: @mohideen-imran-khan Edited. I found the answer.

Comment: @square1001 Thanks for your help. I didn't know about such a sequence, and Google search didn't return this as well.

Comment: @mohideen-imran-khan I have a tip for searching a sequence. Use OEIS (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences / oeis.org) instead. You can input the sequence and find it.

Comment: By the way, if you see something in Wikipedia that's wrong, you can just edit it.

Comment: @square1001 I still do not know how to implement an efficient solution. My code is still slow.

Comment: @square1001 Thank you very much.

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan This is my algorithm but I think there is more efficient algorithm. But I couldn't find efficient algorithm and there was no Internet site. Sorry for inconvenience :-)